# Unable to copy files from old hard drive to new one

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, certificate

Had to format my PC, so I just bought a new and larger SSD drive. I had to move some files from my old HDD, but some files are encrypted. It seems like this doesn't let me copy the files from one drive to another. I am unable to remove the encrpytion in the file properties.

I have found the old files containing the certificate on my old install under `Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates`. I hoped for the best and copied this file to my new install, but that would be too easy, right? When I open my certificate mgr, I find the old certificate but it leaves me this error:

> "This CA Root certificate is not trusted. To enable trust, install
>   this certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store."

So my question is: will I be able to move these files somehow? Or is it impossible if I didn't export the old certificate correctly?

Comment: Can you still boot to the old drive and remove encryption?

Comment: @CharlieRB No, I changed more or less all hardware as well.